# How to trigger a Jenkins job, whenever a new Branch is created in Bitbucket Cloud?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks, bitbucket-api

I am trying to trigger a Jenkins job whenever a new branch is created in Bitbucket cloud. Is there any way to achieve this using Plugins or Web-Hooks or some API calls?

Comment: Try this: https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket/

Comment: @TomerShetah  I don't think this will work! I need to trigger only for Branch creation and not for every commit.

Comment: You can choose it from the `Choose from a full list of triggers`

Comment: Did it work for you? Can I add it as an answer?

Comment: No. I am not able to see the ```Choose from a full list of triggers``` anywhere! Is this for freestyle or pipeline job?